# Vanishing cycles and component groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vanishing-cycles

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a local field $K$ and assume it has toric reduction. Then two classical invariants associated to this are the component group $\Phi(A)=\mathcal{A}_s/\mathcal{A}_s^0$ (where $\mathcal{A}$ is the Neron model) and the character group $M(A)=\text{Hom}(T,\mathbb{G}_m)$. The two are naturally related via the monodromy operator
$$0\to M(A^\vee)\overset{N}{\to} M(A)\to \Phi(A)\to 0.$$
Another construction is the complex of vanishing cycles $R\Phi(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ and a monodromy operator
$$R\Psi(\mathbb{Z}_\ell(1))\to R\Psi(\mathbb{Z}_\ell).$$

The first set of objects works well to understand the reduction of Jacobians of curves, and my question is if vanishing and nearby cylces and their monodromy operator are "valid" generalizations of component groups and if so how I should think about them.